# VF page with controller testing

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller

**Apex Class**

```
  public with sharing class AccContact {

    private integer totalRecs = 0;     
    private integer index = 0;
    private integer blockSize = 2;      

    public list<contact> conlst { get; set; }
    public string getid {get; set;}    
    public list<account> accconts1 { get; set; }

    public List<Account> acclst { get; set; }

    public  AccContact (){
        acclst=[select id,name  from account ];
        system.debug(acclst);
        conlst= getAccContacts();
        totalRecs = [select count() from contact]; 

    } 

     public List<Contact> getAccContacts()
    {
        conlst=[select id,lastname,firstname,email,title,birthdate from contact where AccountId=: getId LIMIT :blockSize OFFSET :index ];
        return conlst;
    }

    public PageReference selacc() {
        getid=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('conlst');
        accconts1=[select id,name,(select id,lastname,firstname,email,title,birthdate from contacts)  from account where id=:getid LIMIT :blockSize OFFSET :index ];
        system.debug(accconts1);
        return null;
    }

    public void beginning()
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    public void previous()
    {
        index = index - blockSize;
    }

    public void next()
    {
        index = index + blockSize;
    }

    public void end()
    {
        index = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,blockSize);
    }        

    public boolean getprev()
    {
        if(index == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }  

    public boolean getnxt()
    {
        if((index + blockSize) > totalRecs)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }         


    public PageReference save1() {
        update conlst;
        PageReference page = new Pagereference('/apex/Mass_Update');
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;

    }
    public void cancel(){
        PageReference page = new Pagereference('/apex/Mass_Update');
        page.setRedirect(true);
    }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="AccContact">
  <apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!save1}" />
<apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true"/>

 <apex:commandButton value="<<" rerender="details" action="{!beginning}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value="<" rerender="details" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value=">" rerender="details" action="{!next}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value=">>" rerender="details" action="{!end}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>      

</apex:pageBlockButtons>

  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acclst}" var="a">

 <apex:column headerValue="Name">
  <apex:commandLink action="{!selacc}">
  <apex:param name="conlst" value="{!a.id}"/>
  <apex:outputText value="{!a.name}"/>
  </apex:commandlink>
  </apex:column>

  <!--accounts-->
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accconts1}" var="a">
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!a.Name}"/>

    <!--contacts-->
   <apex:column headerValue="List contacts">
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccContacts}" var="c">

  <apex:column headerValue="Title">
  <apex:outputField value="{!c.title}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>

      </apex:outputField>
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
  <apex:outputField value="{!c.firstname}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
      </apex:outputField>
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
 <apex:outputField value="{!c.lastname}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
      </apex:outputField>
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column headerValue="Email">
  <apex:outputField value="{!c.email}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
      </apex:outputField>
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
 <apex:outputField value="{!c.birthdate}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
      </apex:outputField>
  </apex:column>


 </apex:pageBlockTable> <!-- End contact-->
 </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable><!--end account-->
  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

How to write test class for this controller?

Comment: What effort you have taken before posting the question. I believe there should be enough help on "How to write test class" Those are all have good solution regardless of code/business logic. 
Please check [ask] section, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some click which can help you for how to write test class,

**Best Practices of Test class**

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

https://salesforcenihar.blogspot.in/2015/11/salesforce-best-practice-for-test.html

http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.in/2015/06/best-practice-for-test-classes-sample.html

https://teachmesalesforce.wordpress.com/category/code-sample/

Find below code for sample test class :

**Apex Class**

```
public Class CreatingAccount{

    public Account createAccount(String name){  //method to create account
         Account acc = new Account();
         acc.Name = name;
         return acc;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class CreateAccountTest{

   static testMethod void testInsertAccount(){

       CreatingAccount ca = new CreatingAccount();
       ca.createAccount(‘TestclassAcc1’);

   }
}
```

Hope it helps you a lot !!

Comment: Thanks! Review materials you shared and it helped. I wrote test class 85% coverage :)

Comment: Now I only have problem with pagination, it not working at all :(

Comment: is it related with test class ? if not then post another question so, people can help you out